# Grep search a multiline string pattern linux

Tags: linux, replace, grep

I have the following text in a file say test.txt :
(Note: There can be more 'Boundary : CRAC' blocks)

```
BOUNDARY: CRAC2OUT
  Boundary Type = INLET
  Location = CRAC_OUT2
  BOUNDARY CONDITIONS:
    FLOW REGIME:
      Option = Subsonic
    END
    HEAT TRANSFER:
      Option = Static Temperature
      Static Temperature = 16 [C]
    END
    MASS AND MOMENTUM:
      Normal Speed = (3.8/1.185)[m^3 s^-1]/area()@CRAC2OUT
      Option = Normal Speed
    END
    TURBULENCE:
      Option = Medium Intensity and Eddy Viscosity Ratio
    END
  END
END
BOUNDARY: CRAC3OUT
  Boundary Type = INLET
  Location = CRAC_OUT3
  BOUNDARY CONDITIONS:
    FLOW REGIME:
      Option = Subsonic
    END
    HEAT TRANSFER:
      Option = Static Temperature
      Static Temperature = 16 [C]
    END
    MASS AND MOMENTUM:
      Normal Speed = (3.8/1.185)[m^3 s^-1]/area()@CRAC3OUT
      Option = Normal Speed
    END
    TURBULENCE:
      Option = Medium Intensity and Eddy Viscosity Ratio
    END
  END
END
BOUNDARY: CRAC4OUT
  Boundary Type = WALL
  Location = CRAC_OUT4
  BOUNDARY CONDITIONS:
    HEAT TRANSFER:
      Option = Adiabatic
    END
    MASS AND MOMENTUM:
      Option = No Slip Wall
    END
    WALL ROUGHNESS:
      Option = Smooth Wall
    END
  END
END
```

I need to search for say CRAC3OUT and replace the value of Static Temperature in its block with 17 in place of 16 and similarly change Normal speed for it with 4.8 instead of 3.8.
I need to change only that block for CRAC3OUT.

How can I use grep or pcregrep to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -i -lne 'if(/^\s*Static Temperature/ && $f==1){s/16/17/g;};
              if(/^\s*Normal Speed =/ && $f==1){s/4\.8/3.8/g;$f=0};
              $f=1 if(/BOUNDARY: CRAC3OUT/);
              print $_' your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) can do that kind of transformations in text. [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) doesn't work fine when you have to keep different number of blank characters, so [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) could be one good option, using a *flag* to change only that block:

```
perl -ne '
    @f = grep { /./s } split /((?>\s+))/;
    if ( $_ =~  m/^BOUNDARY:\s+CRAC3OUT/ ) { $block = 1; }
    if ( $f[1] eq q|BOUNDARY:| ) { $block = 0; }
    if ( $block ) {
        if ( $f[1] eq q|Static| and $f[3] eq q|Temperature| ) {
            $f[7] = 17;
        }
        if ( $f[1] eq q|Normal| and $f[3] eq q|Speed| ) {
            $f[7] =~ s/\d*\.\d*/4.8/;
        }
    }
    printf qq|%s|, join q||, @f;
' test.txt
```

It yields:

```
...
BOUNDARY: CRAC3OUT
  Boundary Type = INLET
  Location = CRAC_OUT3
  BOUNDARY CONDITIONS:
    FLOW REGIME:
      Option = Subsonic
    END
    HEAT TRANSFER:
      Option = Static Temperature
      Static Temperature = 17 [C]
    END
    MASS AND MOMENTUM:
      Normal Speed = (4.8/1.185)[m^3 s^-1]/area()@CRAC3OUT
      Option = Normal Speed
    END
    TURBULENCE:
      Option = Medium Intensity and Eddy Viscosity Ratio
    END
  END
END
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` isn't fit for replacing anything.  You should use `sed` for this by specifying a range to work on, but I find it hard to spcify the range properly with your example.  `sed` also cannot really *parse* complex languages with context (like yours with that block structure).

But if you can live with just processing lines containing `Normal Speed = (` in a block spanning from a line containing `BOUNDARY: CRAC3OUT` to a line containing `BOUNDARY: CRACxOUT` with an `x` ≠ `3`, then you can use this simple `sed` script:

```
sed '/BOUNDARY: CRAC3OUT/,/BOUNDARY: CRAC[^3]OUT/s/\(Normal Speed = (\)[^/]*/\14.8/'
```

But keep in mind that this can fail (i. e. produce unwanted results) in case for example if your `BOUNDARY: CRAC3OUT` block is the last one in the input (no other block follows) but another line containing `Normal Speed = (` follows somewhere in the input.

The script only changes the `3.8` to a `4.8` for brevity.  The change from `17` to `16` is done likewise of course.